# Heroku breaking my Rails + Angular.js app via JS file minification

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a brand new Rails 4.2.0 app with Angular.js on Heroku and I have the following angular.js controller:

```
angular.module("CarDealer.controllers",[]).controller('carsController', function ($scope, carDealerAPIservice) {
  $scope.nameFilter = null;
  $scope.carsList = [];

  carDealerAPIservice.getCars().success(function (response) {
    $scope.carsList = response;
  });
});
```

and in my view:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="carsController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Find vehicle..." class="form-control", autofocus="true"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul data-ng-repeat="car in carsList | filter: nameFilter">
    <li>{{ car.model_name }} - {{ car.year }} </li>
  </ul>
```

But when I open the page nothing renders and I have the following in my console:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- carsController

Everything works fine in development mode but in production mode I find myself stuck with this problem.

What can I do to overcome this situation? I've tried disabling asset compressing and all but did not succeed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid problems with minified sources ALWAYS inject dependencies using following syntax:

```
controller('carsController', ['$scope', 'carDealerAPIservice', function ($scope, carDealerAPIservice) { 
//code
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular files get messed up when minified with the asset pipeline unless you use a special array syntax to handle strings in dependency injection. The easiest way to do this in rails is to just add the [ng annotate](https://github.com/kikonen/ngannotate-rails) gem and then you don't have to modify your code. Another option is to turn off uglification:

```
# config/environments/***.rb
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)
```

Your code works in development mode because it's not being minified.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it did not work and I got the exact same error